# Difference between "蝈蝈", "蟋蟀" and "蛐蛐" (Also: 纺织娘)?

Tags: difference

I keep seeing "蝈蝈", "蟋蟀" and "蛐蛐" being used interchangeably in Mandarin for some topolectical words.

蝈蝈 seems to refer to a:

> katydid

蟋蟀 seems to be a:

> cricket

and 蛐蛐 also seems to be a:

> cricket

But how can they be used interchangeably? Is it a mistake? Are there some differences? If so, what are they?

---

I did find this on [zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/25425465):

> 蛐蛐和蟋蟀指蟋蟀总科，蝈蝈指螽斯科人们喜欢养的种类

So, no difference between 蛐蛐 and 蟋蟀 then?

Why would 蝈蝈 be confused with 蛐蛐 and 蟋蟀 then?

**Also**: how does 纺织娘 play in here?

Comment: 蛐蛐 is the common name of 蟋蟀

Comment: The same thing can have different names in different places. I am from the south part and I always use 蟋蟀 for crickets, though I know the word 蛐蛐.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to wikipedia(and my understanding as a native speaker):
蝈蝈,纺织娘 should be two sub species belong to the family: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tettigoniidae

蛐蛐,蟋蟀 is the same thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_(insect)